# Calling a parent function from child gets called but doesn't change the state

Tags: react-native

I am working on a React Native app where I'm calling a parent function from child component and it gets called but it doesn't change the state. Basically I am opening a modal from child and want to change the state of parent component through changing something on modal and close the modal.

Here's the parent:

```js
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this._toggleModal = this._toggleModal.bind(this)
this.state = {
  isActive: false}}                             

  _toggleModal = async() => {
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible })
  }

  doSomthing(x) {
    console.log(x)
    this._toggleModal;
  }

   render() {
    return (
     <RateModal toggleCall1={this.doSomthing}/>
     )}
```

And here's the child:

```js
  ratingCompleted = async(rating)=> {
    console.log("Rating is: " + rating)
    await this.props.toggleCall1(false)
  }
```

Here I'm getting `false` props from the child when rating is given but it doesn't change the state of the parent. How to resolve this?

Comment: If i do this like this._toggleModal(); Then it shows unhandled promise rejection and this._toggleModal() is not a function.

Comment: Have you bound `doSomthing()` in the constructor?

Comment: I have updated the question. I did bind like the updated question.

Comment: No you didn't. You bound `_toggleModal` which didn't even need to be bound because it's an arrow function. You need to bind `doSomthing` or turn it into an arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
doSomthing = (x) => {
  console.log(x)
  this._toggleModal();
}
```

you either need to bind this context or change the function to arrow function

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the function,

```
this._toggleModal()
```

Comment: If i do this like this._toggleModal(); Then it shows unhandled promise rejection and this._toggleModal() is not a function.

Comment: You need to bind this to doSomthing function in constructor like- this.doSomthing = this.doSomthing.bind(this)

Comment: Also remove async await from child component function.